# Stars and Bars with Multiple Restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion, integer-partitions

I've seen this [Number of solutions to $x_1 +x_2 +x_3 +x_4 = 1097$ with multiple "at least" restrictions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4286360/number-of-solutions-to-x-1-x-2-x-3-x-4-1097-with-multiple-at-least-rest?rq=1)

and this [Stars and bars (combinatorics) with multiple bounds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/760950/stars-and-bars-combinatorics-with-multiple-bounds).

But I am having trouble answering this problem

> Two chess players, A and B, are going to play 7 games. Each game has three possible outcomes: a win for A (which is a loss for B), a draw (tie), and a loss for A (which is a win for B). A win is worth 1 point, a draw is worth .5 points, and a loss is worth 0 points.
>
> How many possible outcomes for the individual games are there, such that A ends up with 4 points and B ends up with 3 points?

I know how to do this normally with cases and I get 357, which is correct. But I am interested in doing it a stars and bars way where the answer is some variation on $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 .. x_7 = 8$

Basically, we can find the # of ways for A to get 4 points by counting each star as a half point, so we have 8 stars to spread accross with 6 bars.

But each cell cannot hold more than 2 of the points.

The total number of solutions without restriction is ${ 14 \choose 6} = 3003$

But now we want it for $x_1 <=2 , x_2 <=2 ... x_7 <= 2$

So I decided that I could calculate when one of the cells has 3 or more, and then through symmetry multiply by 7 and then through PIE get rid of duplicates.

So I decided

${ 14 \choose 6} - { 11 \choose 6} * 7 + { 10 \choose 6} * 7 ... + { 6 \choose 6} * 7$ should give me the answer, as we remove all the cases that break our rule of only 2 stars per cell max. But this gives 805 as the answer which is wrong.

I think maybe now I must calculate $x_1 <= 2$ and $x_2 <= 2$  ..., or for $x_1=0$ $x_1=1$ and $x_1 =3$ and the same for all 7 variables but then I'm basically just counting cases/doing it the original way I did it.

Comment: Can you explain how you applied PIE in more detail? EG I was expecting a ${ 7 \choose 2 } $ term in there, corresponding to the case when (at least) 2 cells are 3 or more.

Comment: Well I thought that if we say $x_1$ has 3 or more stars, we have ${11 /choose 6}$ ways to spread the remaning. However when we spread the remaining we are including when $x_1$ has 4 or more as well, as the combinations are going to include those as well, so then I add them back, then subtract out when 5 etc... But perhaps I need to include exclude the restrictions and not this ( seems like the logic isn't there for that answer)

Comment: Work through the details of the PIE instead of just winging it. From what you wrote, it seems like you don't quite understand how PIE works.

Comment: Ok I will add an edit soon

Comment: Does this look correct @CalvinLin , I think the way is very tedious to finish no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be
$$
{14\choose6}-7{11\choose6}+{7\choose2}{8\choose6}=357
$$
${7\choose2}$ because there are that many ways to choose two of the seven $x_i$ to exceed two; only three terms to compute because it's impossible for more than two of the $x_i$ to exceed two; and ${8\choose6}$ because I don't know where you got ${10\choose6}$ from.

Comment: Thanks, Gerry, yeah I missed the fact that 3+3+3 > 8 while trying to do it the first time, glad to see I was in the neighborhood of correct.

Comment: Which of the cases take into account when one of the $x_i$ exceeds 5,6,7?

@GerryMyerson

Comment: Oh basically the first one subtracts all away, but then when we multiply by 7 there are some things double counted, for example *`** | *** |** | | | |, and then we add back what we subtracted away too many times?

Comment: I don't know what all those asterisks mean, but the 2nd term subtracts (for example) $3+3+2+0+0+0+0=8$ twice, once because $x_1>2$, and again because $x_2>2$, when it really should only be subtracted once. So, it has to be put back, and that's what the third term does. That's the whole idea behind Inclusion-Exclusion!